# Check if row exists so user cannot tamper with input

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, exists

NOTE: I've edit the whole post, trying to make it clearer.

I'm terrible at getting my question clear, but this is my last try.
I got this which gets sent when clicking the button;

```
                echo"Auto/Prijs<br><br><select name='autos'>";
            echo"<br><br>";

            $sql = "SELECT `garage`.`id`, `car_id`, `schade`, `naam`, `prijs` FROM `garage` LEFT JOIN `cars` ON (`garage`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`) WHERE `user_id`=".ID." ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT ".($page * 10).", 10";
$sql = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $i = 1;
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    echo"


<option value='".$res['car_id']."'>".$res['naam']."</option><br>
    ";
```

This is a dropdown, showing carnames instead of car_id's.
Now, the car_id is not unique, but refers to a car. The 'id' in the 'garage' table IS unique. Am I able to like call the 'id' too, and on sending check if that ID is actually the sent 'car_id'? Because, you can tamper the sent car_id and simply change it.

This happens on sending:

```
if(isset($_POST['start'])){
$prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
$carr = $_POST['autos'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `automarkt` WHERE `seller_id`=".ID." LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `automarkt`(`seller_id`, `prijs`, `car_id`) VALUES (".ID.", ".$prijs.", ".$carr.")") or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm out of idea's, and can't get clear enough on what I need to do. I need to check if the sent car_id is actually in the 'user''s garage. (Trying to do it by checking the unique entry 'id' in the 'garage' table.

Comment: `.ID.` looks strange.

Comment: Don't work with mysql_query, start using PDO!

Comment: ID seems to be a constant, is it a constant or a variable $ID?

Comment: `$carr` looks like it introduces a SQL injection vulnerability into this application.

Comment: Can someone maybe like hook me up on skype? Or ICQ ? It's pretty hard to explain I think.

.ID. just means the ID of the user that's on the page. It's used in the whole source. $carr is the car_id being posted.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by matching rows.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `garage` WHERE `car_id`=".$carr." AND `user_id`=".ID) or die(mysql_error());

} elseif(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
        $msgs = bad("x");
```

Thanks for replies.